# Richter scale equation

Tags: geophysics, earthquake

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale#Richter_magnitudes), the equation for finding magnitude according to the Richter scale is $M_\mathrm{L} = \log_{10} A - \log_{10} A_0(\delta)$.

However, it is rather ambiguous as to the effect of epicentral distance ($\delta$) on the equation. Other sources seem to suggest that the distance from the epicentre is taken into account with the function of $A_0$, but do not specify how. Is it just basic multiplication, or is it actually more complex?

Comment: After continuing to look, I have noticed wikipedia mentions correlation tables. Does anyone know what these are?